# multiple nested forms within a ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to use multiple nested attributes within a form, though only the first set of attributes appears to be appearing.

Below is the HAML template

```
.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--10-col.mdl-cell--1-offset
  %h3.mdl-typography--display-1= t('.account_title')
  = form.fields_for :address do |address_fields|
    .mdl-grid
      .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--6-col
        = address_fields.text_field :first_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
        = address_fields.label :first_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
      .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--6-col
        = address_fields.text_field :last_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
        = address_fields.label :last_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
      .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--6-col
        = form.text_field :name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
        = form.label :name, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
      .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--6-col
        = form.email_field :email, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
        = form.label :email, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
  %h3.mdl-typography--display-1= t('.bank_title')
  = form.fields_for :account do |account_fields|
    .mdl-grid
      .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--6-col
        = account_fields.text_field :bsb, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
        = account_fields.label :bsb, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
      .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--6-col
        = account_fields.text_field :account_number, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
        = account_fields.label :account_number, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
      .mdl-textfield.mdl-js-textfield.mdl-textfield--floating-label.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--12-col
        = account_fields.text_field :account_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input'
        = account_fields.label :account_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__label'
```

Definitions in Model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['address1'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trading_hours
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, :reject_if => lambda { |t| ( t['display_number'].gsub(/\D+/, '').blank?) }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
```

Comment: Can you show the params being passed from your rails server log?

Answer (score -1):

On the parent you need to build each additional attributes for the form (this is a new form that is, i believe you can do this in the controller under def new...)

```
def new
  @parent.address.build
  @parent.trading_hours.build
  @parent.phones.build
  @parent.account.build
end
```

if you arent trying to do a new form let me know and update the question

Comment: This seems to be find, but goes against the Rails way according to the documentation that Rubymine is telling me

Comment: lol okay if you say so! attributes wont show if there is no attributes built on the object.

Comment: This code shouldn't be in the controller, as only 1 method should be called. This isn't best practices, it goes against the FAT models, Skinny Controllers

Comment: okay sure, if rubymine is telling you that im not sure what to say. Here is a link to the explanation. Without building the attributes they wont render. I guess i havent been doing to best practice... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms in 9.2 " if a person has no addresses it renders nothing."

Comment: im not sure why you marked my answer down, it fixed the problem. After doing some looking around to check where else it could go, there is 2 places people seem to put it, in the view under a helper or in the controller... Either way you need to use the build to get it to work... kinda uncool to -1 it.